# Enum class doesn't return values I need

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, enums, controller

I have created an `enumerated` class that contains 2 values. What I want is to create a `controller` that returns the enumerations that exist along with their values.

This is my Enum Class:

```
@Getter
public enum ModesEnum {

   ASSOCIATED ("A", "Associated"), DISASSOCIATED ("D", "Disassociated");

   private String key;
   private String value;

   private ModesEnum(String key, String value) {
       this.key = key;
       this.value = value;
   }

   @JsonValue
   public String getValor() {
       return value;
   }

   @JsonValue
   public String getKey() {
       return key;
   }

   private static final Map<String, String> mapClassEnum;

   static {
       mapClassEnum = new HashMap<>();
       Arrays.stream(values()).forEach(elem -> {
           mapClassEnum.put(elem.getValue(), elem.getKey());
           mapClassEnum.put(elem.getValue(), elem.getValor());
   });
}
```

My Controller class:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/modesEnum")
    public ResponseEntity<ModesEnum[]> getAll(){
        return new ResponseEntity<>(ModesEnum.values(), null, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

however when executing the controller it gives me the following error:

```
 Problem with definition of AnnotedClass ModesEnum Multiple 'as-value' properties defined ModesEnum #getKey() vs ModesEnum [0]
```

How can I return in my `controller` something like this `JSON`?:

```
{
   { key: "A", value : "Associated"},
   { key: "D", value : "Disassociated"}
}
```

Comment: You have two different fields annotated with `@JsonValue`. Shouldn’t you have only one defined as such to ensure that one becomes your enum value when de/serialized? That’s what the error message seems to indicate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [JsonValue documentation](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.6/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonValue.html) says that only one method may be annotated with `@JsonValue`.

> At most one method of a Class can be annotated with this annotation; if more than one is found, an exception may be thrown.

You can try to serialize both `key` and `value` in a `toString()` method (annotate `toString()` with `@JsonValue`).

Another option might be to use [@JsonProperty](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonProperty.html) on your enum instances:

```
@JsonProperty("associated")
ASSOCIATED ("A", "Associated"), 
@JsonProperty("disassociated")
DISASSOCIATED ("D", "Disassociated");
```